# Kable footnotes with math equation and alphabetic notes

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable

I'm having trouble with kable and R Markdown. I would like to create a table with footnotes:
1. a bit of math formula ([image]), 
2. with alphabetical notes, 
3. and I would like the notes a and b to also show up next to var_a and var_b in superscript.

I can make the table, but the moment I add the footnotes I get an error msg.

```
var_a <- rep(0, 3)
var_b <- rep(1,3)
var_c <- rep(2, 3)

df <- data.frame(var_a=var_a, var_b=var_b, var_c=var_c)

kable(df, "latex", caption = "title", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  add_footnote("Standard errors in parenthesis. P-values in brackets.", "P-values from Wald-test for $H_0$ Hazard Ratio = 1.",
               footnote_order = c("alphabet", "alphabet"))
```

EDIT:

This is the error msg I get:

```
Error in add_footnote(., "Standard errors in parenthesis. P-values in brackets.",  : 
  unused argument (footnote_order = c("alphabet", "alphabet"))
```

Comment: Consider adding the error msg to your question.

Comment: footnote_order isn't an argument of add_footnote.  Rather use the notation argument as in  `add_footnote(label = c("Standard errors in parenthesis. P-values in brackets.", "P-values from Wald-test for $H_0$ Hazard Ratio = 1."),
               notation = "alphabet")`

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I'm not a big fan of the pipe operator, when you make complex functions you tend to miss some tiny issues, like putting your footnotes in a vector:

```
mytable <- kable(df, "latex", caption = "title", booktabs = T)

mytable <- kable_styling(mytable)

add_footnote(mytable,c("Standard errors in parenthesis. P-values in brackets.",
                  "P-values from Wald-test for $H_0$ Hazard Ratio = 1.") )
```

I delete `footnote_order` I don't understand why you use it? And I'm not able to make it work...

I you want footnote to generate `$H_0$` instead of `\$H\_0\$`, you have to write:

```
add_footnote(mytable,c("Standard errors in parenthesis. P-values in brackets.",
                       "P-values from Wald-test for $H_0$ Hazard Ratio = 1."), escape = FALSE )
```

Comment: thanks for this. ```mytable <- kable_styling(AA)``` doesn't seem to go through with the error msg "Object 'AA' not found". Any idea why? Also, I am still wondering about the point 3 in my question. Is it possible to put the alphabetical notes next to the variables in superscript?

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit, I should have replace `AA` by `mytable`.

Comment: HI, Thanks for the edit. I am still struggling with making ```\$H\_0\$```. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it work by adding , `escape = FALSE` in add_footnote.